# How to get count() of number of returned rows and data from them in same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
select
    problem_comments.user_id ,
    problem_comment_id ,
    problem_id ,
    first_name  ,
    count(problem_comment_id) num
from problem_comments
left join users on problem_comments.user_id = users.user_id
where problem_id = 222
group by problem_comments.comment
```

and it is a basic join of a table where problems are listed and another table where comments for that problem are listed.

What I am trying to do with `count(problem_comment_id)` is see how many comments are in a problem so I can display that count. The problem with the current query is that it returns 3 rows because there are 3 comments for this problem.  But in the column "num" it always lists 1.

How can I keep getting back the same data of problems and comments, but also get how many total comments there are?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag, so... You can use the `num_rows` functions after you execute the query.

[Here is some information if you are using `mysqli`.](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

[And for `PDO`.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

If you're using the `mysql` extension (and shame on you, if so!), [you can use `mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would work for you

```
select
    problem_comments.user_id ,
    problem_comment_id ,
    problem_id ,
    first_name  ,
    commentCount AS num
from problem_comments
left join users on problem_comments.user_id = users.user_id
left join
(select problem_id as comment_count_problem_id, COUNT(problem_comment_id) as commentCount
 from problem_comments
 group by problem_comments.problem_id) t ON t.comment_count_problem_id = problem_id
where problem_id = 222
```